# rewrite url with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to rewrite a url like test.php?type=$1&val=$2
type will always be a string where as val could be a number or a string. I came up with the following 
`test/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9|]+)/([0-9]+).html` but as it was expected it will not work with something lke `test/hello-world/23.html` How can i included dashes in the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape them, so if you had

```
test/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-|]+)/([0-9]+).html
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a question about regular expressions to me. `test/([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9|-]+)/([0-9]+).html` should do. It's important to put the dash at the *end* of the character class.